# React: Blank Page Issue When Rendering Product Listing Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react
I am trying to display the list of products in the UI with the image.
But when I include the below component

its is showing blank white page.
Can you let me know how to fix it.
Provding my codesnippet and sandbox below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-bt1qht?file=package.json,src%2Fcomponents%2FProductListing.jsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FLogin.jsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FImageSearch.jsx,src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ProductListing = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        // const response = await axios.get('/api/products');
        const response = await axios.get(
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
        );
        console.log('response', response);
        setProducts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {error ? (
        <p>Error fetching products</p>
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {products.map((product) => (
            <li key={product.id}>
              {product.name} - ${product.price}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductListing;
```

Answer (score -1):

First: You don't need to import `React`.

About your issue, it is due to an import error (as you may have seen in the terminal). The thing is you're using

```
import { ProductListing } from './components/ProductListing';
```

instead of

```
import ProductListing from './components/ProductListing';
```

Why? because in your component you used an `export default`. You can learn more about JavaScript exports [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-export-default-in-javascript/) or [here](https://youtu.be/KeBxopnhizw) on YouTube.